# atualizar a div com o valor do checkbox marcado

Tags: php, javascript, html

vamos direto ao assunto, agradeço desde já.

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[name='nomes[]']")];
const res = document.getElementById("resultado");

inputs.forEach(x => x.addEventListener("change", ()=> {
  //esta função corre quando houve alteração de um dos checkboxes
  res.innerHTML = ""; //limpar o resultado

  //passar em todos os inputs e adicionar o seu value e <br> se tiver checked
  inputs.forEach (y => res.innerHTML += y.checked ? y.value + "<br>" : "");
}));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="nomes[]" value="01" />
<input type="checkbox" name="nomes[]" value="02" />
<input type="checkbox" name="nomes[]" value="03" />
<input type="checkbox" name="nomes[]" value="04" />

<div id="resultado">
  <input type="hidden" name="total" value="seria a soma dos valores">
  <input type="hidden" name="nomes" value="seria os nomes[] marcados(A,B,C..)">
</div>
```

o código esta funcionando como deveria, porém gostaria de saber como fazer alguma alteração para que os input's dentro da DIV recebam os dados em vez da DIV.

Comment: Qual é o nome que queres mostrar? Todos têm o mesmo nome... :/

Comment: os nomes estão sendo trazidos do BD, mas pra exemplificar seria "Teclado, Mouse, Fone, Monitor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")];
const res = document.getElementById("resultado");
const total = res.querySelector('[name="total"]');
const nomes = res.querySelector('[name="nomes"]');


const calcular = () => {
  total.value = inputs.filter(el => el.checked).reduce((sum, el) => sum + Number(el.value), 0);
  nomes.value = inputs.filter(el => el.checked).map(el => el.name).join(',');
};

inputs.forEach(x => x.addEventListener("change", calcular));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="Teclado" value="01" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Mouse" value="02" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Fone" value="03" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Monitor" value="04" />

<div id="resultado">
  <input type="text" name="total" value="seria a soma dos valores">
  <input type="text" name="nomes" value="seria os nomes[] marcados(A,B,C..)">
</div>
```

A ideia é modificar o `.value` do input de destino. Repara que para o exemplo usei `type="text"` mas podes er `hidden` como tinhas.

Assim, usando o `.name` com um `.filter` antes e `.join(',')` crias a string de nomes; usando um redutor com um `.filter` antes fazes a soma.

Comment: Entendi, Perfeito!

Comment: uma pergunta Sergio, se eu quiser mostrar a soma dos valores fora do input eu poderia ?

Comment: @RonaldodeLima sim, claro. Para isso em vex de `total.value` usa o elemento que queres e depois `.value` ou `.innerHTML` caso seja um input ou outro tipo de elemento